# Integrating $\sqrt{r^2 - x^2 - z^2}$

Tags: integration, volume

I need to integrate the following piece:
$\int \sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - z^2} \, dx$.

This is what I tried:

- $\int \sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - z^2} \, dx = \int (R^2 - x^2 - z^2)^\frac{1}{2} \, dx$
- Substitute $u = (R^2 - x^2 - z^2)^\frac{1}{2}, du = \frac{du}{dx}dx = \frac{1}{2}(R^2 - x^2 - z^2)^\frac{-1}{2} * 2x dx, dx = \frac{(R^2 - x^2 - z^2)^\frac{1}{2}}{x} du = \frac{u}{x}du$
- But I'm stuck.

The expected result is: $\frac{R^2- z^2}{2} * \arcsin(\frac{y}{\sqrt{R^2 - z^2}}) + \frac{y}{2}*\sqrt{R^2-z^2-y^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $R^2-z^2=a^2$. Then, substitute $x=a\sin\theta$.

$$I=\int\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx=\int a^2\cos^2\theta d\theta$$

Use $\cos^2\theta=\frac{1+\cos2\theta}{2}$

Comment: Thanks! How do I get the arctan then?

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive Where should you get the $\arctan$? Do you mean $\arcsin$?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Misspelled there.

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive You will have to integrate $\frac12$ which will give you $\frac{\theta}{2}$, where $\theta=\arcsin(\frac xa)$.

Comment: Seems fine. Thanks again!